# 'git diff' documentation refers to 'source' and 'destination' but doesn't say which corresponds to index

Tags: git

The documentation for 'git diff' refers to 'source' files (default output prefix is 'a/') and 'destination' files (default output prefix is 'b/'). My question is, does 'source' refer to the file(s) in the index (staging area) and 'destination' the file(s) in the work directory, or is it the other way around?

Answer (score 5):

The answer to that is both no and yes.<sup>1</sup>

`git diff` *can* compare things to your staging area, but it doesn't always do that. Let's consider these common cases:

1. `git diff`, with no additional arguments.  This means "compare the tree associated with the index against the tree in the current working directory."  In this case, "source" is the index.
2. `git diff HEAD`, with no additional arguments.  This means "compare the tree in `HEAD` against the tree in the working directory."  In this case, the index is not used at all.  The same is true if you name a specific revision or branch.
3. `git diff --cached`, with no additional arguments.  This means "compare the tree in `HEAD` against the tree in the index."  In this case, "destination" is the index.
4. `git diff --cached <rev>`: this is the same as #3 but using the specified revision as the source.
5. `git diff <rev1> <rev2>`: this compares the trees of the two specified revisions, ignoring both the index and the work-tree.

Thus, sometimes the staging area is either the source or the destination, and sometimes it is not used at all.

---

It is said: go not to the Elves for answers, for they will say both no and yes.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Source is index, destination is work. All I had to do was look at the work file. D'oh! Total brain fart.